# Merging a git stash with the current head

Tags: git, merge, github

I did a git stash on production but then others pushed more changes to the repository. So is there a way merge them both together. I can see the changes in the stash but not in the current head.

Git fsck shows

git fsck
dangling tree b00308a00025bbe3eaa370b326d82dae5b9403cc
dangling tree e714ea6c807bbdd039abfe8a8fb779c02403c3b3
dangling tree cc1e0f3768af3e5cb22fdfde7603f663c1812d78
dangling tree f51f1aa3298e21affb0b2ee31343f2c47df438c3
dangling tree b530b1163c677de735d82d7c11081921b35807ae
dangling tree bfb862564922f45cc272daac3e1d131fd254a8ed
dangling tree cdd02c02d05dfbc928c4ce9123fc4c360299395c
dangling tree b851786925e57bb2d7e71badefc5171b9110ccd5
dangling tree ae5caf6ede4e4b5f9c344ac3e749aaed6bee5e96
dangling tree e56ad067c775f25d18cab3520f3f1add2731c67d
dangling tree 1871498602802cbe324ed746395ac300884622ce
dangling tree c0f61e31611cf5fbed159737e9f04b9b214ed663
dangling tree 7bf8bdd7e6cca37cd1929473d50d2914cc1f94c1

Thanks.

Comment: `git fsck` doesn't have much to do with stash. To see stashed changes, you'd use `git stash list` to see the list of stashes, and `git stash show` to see the actual changes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the points of stash is that you can reapply it anywhere. You stashed away your changes, so they are stored as relative to the commit that was checked out then, but now that you've checked out a different commit, you're free to use `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` to apply the stashed changes. (`pop` deletes the stash once they're successfully applied; `apply` leaves it.)

Of course, if things have changed significantly, the stashed changes may no longer apply cleanly. Git will treat this as a merge conflict, and you can resolve it as you would any other merge conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Merging in git drives me crazy, git mergetool is so confusing. Could you also point to tips for merging.

Comment: @pal4life: I never use mergetool. I just merge, look at the conflict markers in the file, and figure out which versions I want to keep. You'll find tons of questions about merging here if you search, though, and you're welcome to ask separate questions too (if they're not duplicates). (And as far as mergetool is concerned, it's just a way to launch a merge tool of your choice, which hopefully will be *less* confusing to you. If it's more confusing, you're doing it wrong.)

Comment: Thanks for the response here, I reread this comment and it makes a lot of sense. I saw you have answered a bunch of questions in Git, you could be a great person to point to new users how to get started on learning Git. My young cousin just got introduced to version control systems, it will be nice if you could suggest a sequence on whats the best way to go through learning about Git in terms of the resources out there. Pardon for a detour comment, although no other way I saw for messaging you. Thanks.

Comment: @pal4life Unfortunately I've not really been heavily using git lately and haven't kept up with the documentation, so while I still remember an awful lot, I'm not sure what the best docs are - my best guesses would be [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) and [the official docs](http://git-scm.com/documentation). There are probably some other questions about it on SO if you search around.

Comment: "you're free to use git stash apply".  But when I try this, I get: "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:"  Duh!  That's WHY I want to merge them!  Git is so frustrating!  Bad tool.

Comment: For me, when I apply the stash, git takes me to detatched head state. Why?